android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
In my android app I use Facebook Audience Network so my manifest.xml looks like this:
<activity
  android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
  tools:replace="android:theme" />

It works well on 99% of devices, but some users are experiencing this bug:
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.my.app/com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
  caused by: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3630)
  caused by: android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)

In my android vitals console seems to be a specific error of this device model/android versions:
LGE Nexus 5X / Android 8 & 13
Is there something I can do to mitigate this exception?
